# Finding the ESX/ESXi host in vSphere cluster on which a virtual machine is running programmatically via REST API

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

For any powered on VM in a given folder I want to retrieve its IP address and the ESXi host it's running on. I'm haveing problems finding an REST API endpoint to retrieve the ESXi host a VM is running on. Albeit I'm able to retrieve the IP addresses of the VMs like so:

###### 1. Get Session ID

```
curl -X "POST" "https://vsphere.company.tld/rest/com/vmware/cis/session" \
     -H 'vmware-use-header-authn: test' \
     -u 'username:password'
```

Output

```json
{
  "value": "random-session-id"
}
```

###### 2. Get all VMs from a folder

```
curl "https://vsphere.company.tld/rest/vcenter/vm?filter.power_states=POWERED_ON&filter.folders=group-v40515" \
     -H 'vmware-api-session-id: random-session-id' \
     -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Output

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "memory_size_MiB": 4096,
      "vm": "vm-40572",
      "name": "runner-br2z81xk-1657760400-7de8fc3e",
      "power_state": "POWERED_ON",
      "cpu_count": 2
    },
    {
      "memory_size_MiB": 4096,
      "vm": "vm-40573",
      "name": "runner-br2z81xk-1657760400-a2d27360",
      "power_state": "POWERED_ON",
      "cpu_count": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

###### 3. Get details (IP address) of VM

```
curl "https://vsphere.company.tld/rest/vcenter/vm/vm-40572/guest/identity" \
     -H 'vmware-api-session-id: random-session-id' \
     -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Output

```json
{
  "value": {
    "full_name": {
      "args": [],
      "default_message": "Other 4.x or later Linux (64-bit)",
      "id": "vmsg.guestos.other4xLinux64Guest.label"
    },
    "name": "OTHER_4X_LINUX_64",
    "ip_address": "192.168.14.19",
    "family": "LINUX",
    "host_name": "runner-br2z81xk-1657760400-7de8fc3e"
  }
}
```

Does one know a way to retrieve the ESXi host for a given VM? I can see the ESXi host easily from the vSphere web UI. But don't find a suitable API endpoint in the [vCenter api documentation](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reference implementations for several languages ([Ruby](https://github.com/ManageIQ/rbvmomi2) [Python](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) [Java](https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-java) [Go](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi)) of the VSphere API (partly by VMware themselves) you could use, standalone or to embed in your own software.

If you want to do it yourself, more power to you - the codebases at least give you a place to find out what you are doing wrong.

To accomplish what you seek in [govmomi](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi):

```bash
$ govc vm.info myvm | grep 'IP address:' | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' '
192.168.0.1
$ govc vm.info myvm | grep 'Host:' | awk {'print $2'}
myesxisrv01
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a filters given to the api endpoint **/rest/vcenter/vm**

For example if you want to fetch the VM <==> esxi host mapping just do -

- List all esxi hosts using **/rest/vcenter/host**

  - For each host do

    - **/rest/vcenter/vm?hosts=${hostIdentifier}**

This will return you the vms associated with the given esxi host

For more details : https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm/get/